# Interpret transformation of polynomial $ \mapsto \mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've got the following task in a trial-test:

The transformation
$T: P_3 → R^4 $ is given by $T(p) = (p(1), p´(1), p´´(1), p´´´(1))$
Prove that T is a bijective linear transformation.

How is this to be interpreted?
I assume $P=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$ and $p(1), p´(1)$ ... is P and its derivatives with x=1.
However, the answer explains:
$T(1) = (1,0,0,0), $
$T(x) = (1,1,0,0), $
$T(x^2) = (1,2,2,0)$,
$T(x^3) = (1,3,3,6)$

$[T]_{S´→S}$ =
| 1  1  1  1 | 
| 0  1  2  3 | 
| 0  0  2  6 | 
| 0  0  0  6 | 
where S´ is the standardbasis for $P_3$ and S is the standardbasis for $R^4$

What is the reasoning for supplying $x^n$ to T? How can T(1) = (1,0,0,0) and T(x) = (1,1,0,0)?

Comment: Have you gone through the basics of a linear mapping? Basis, linear combination, etc..

Comment: You should be able to recognize a base of $P_3$. Since you're unable to do that I'd recommend to review your basics of vector spaces before going to linear maps.

Comment: @jjagmath I will, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $P(x)=1$, then:

- $P(1)=1$;
- $P'(1)=0$;
- $P''(1)=0$;
- $P'''(1)=0$

and therefore $T(1)=(1,0,0,0)$.

On the other hand, if $Q(x)=x$, then

- $Q(1)=1$;
- $Q'(1)=1$;
- $Q''(1)=0$;
- $Q'''(1)=0$

and therefore $T(x)=(1,1,0,0)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
However, I dont understand why I should assume P(x) = 1?

Comment: Because your goal is to compute $T(1)$, and that means to compute $T\bigl(P(x)\bigr)$, with $P(x)=1$.

Comment: I was probably a bit unclear: T(1) = (1,0,0,0) was given only in the answer to the question. It was not present in the question itself.

Comment: And you've asked “How can $T(1) = (1,0,0,0)$ and $T(x) = (1,1,0,0)$?” and I've answered that question. Isn't that what you wanted? If not, *what* did you want?

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning as to why T(1), T(x), T(x²), T(x³) is used in the answer. Why supply x^n when the question only ever supply 1, as in p(1), p´(1) and so on?

Comment: @LockChunk A linear transformation is determined by its action on the basis. Therefore, $T(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3)=aT(1)+bT(x)+cT(x^2)+dT(x^3)$. I do agree that the answer, as given, is wonky because we must first prove that $T$ is linear.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't mean your answer, I mean the answer given in Lock's book.